# How to create an Outlook 2007 Context Menu for within message right click?

Tags: c#, vsto, contextmenu, add-in, outlook-2007

So I have become aware that there is no simple way of adding a context menu (within the email message) to Outlook 2007, as there is no API for it. Does anyone know of any hack/hook that would be able to add functionality to the right click context menu **WITHIN the message body?**. Any other possible solutions would be greatly appreciated. Smart Tags are also deprecated, but a simple example of creating a smart tag library that can be installed via click once would also be appreciated (If such a thing can be done).

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/59e29895-7f5f-465e-bcb4-1082306207b2
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/996a438f-327b-4b73-b9a7-7bffd7b6fefb/

**EDIT: I would also attempt to use smart tags, but the sdk link is broken for me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms123402.aspx**

EDIT: If I get some more reputation I will add a bounty for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is simply impossible, regardless of the hack.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you memoryhack one of the existing items and call different function on click...but it will get waaay too hacky like that.